# document.getElementById not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a .ascx ComboBox user control whose source is defined as below.

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ComboBoxControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControl_ComboBoxControl" %> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0px solid red">   
       <tr>
            <td class="DropDownLook"  style="vertical-align: top" colspan="2">
            <div style="vertical-align: top;width:150px;">                
                <div id="divCheckBoxList" ClientIDMode = "AutoID" runat="server" class="DivCheckBoxList">                    
                <div id = "dvComboAll" >
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" ClientIDMode = "AutoID" CssClass="CheckBoxList leftPaddingforcombo" Text="ALL" ToolTip="ALL" />
                    </div>
                    <div >
                   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkMultipleValues" ClientIDMode = "AutoID" runat="server" CssClass="CheckBoxList" 
                        Width="176px">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in the UserControl's .cs code behind file, i have below line of code

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
   {    chkMultipleValues.Attributes.Add("onclick", "FindSelectedItems(this," + chkAll.ClientID + "');");
   }
```

In the .aspx where i'm using my ComboBox control, i have below peace of javascript code.

```
if(document.getElementById('hdnSelectedValues').value.trim() == '')
        {
            document.getElementById('dvErrorMsg').style.display = "block";
            if(navigator.appName!="Netscape")
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentBody_lblErrorMsg').innerHTML = DisplayMessage(3);
            else
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentBody_lblErrorMsg').innerHTML = 'No parameters selected.';
            return false;
        }
```

In IE 11, if i select all options in my multi-select ComboBoxControl, `document.getElementById('hdnSelectedValues').value.trim()` contains all the options in the control.

Problem i'm having is, if i select any number of options from the ComboBoxControl but not ALL, `document.getElementById('hdnSelectedValues').value.trim()` returns as empty.

Below is code for my "FindSelectedItems" javascript function that i'm attaching to my ComboBoxControl code behind page_load event.

Note that it working fine in IE 5 document mode. This issue is appearing in IE 11.

```
function FindSelectedItems(sender, obj) {
if (obj) {
    var ChkAll = document.getElementById(obj.id);
}
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentBody_lblErrorMsg').innerHTML = '';
var valuetodisplay = document.getElementById('ctl00_hdnSelectedValuesForDisplay').value;
document.getElementById('dvErrorMsg').style.display = "none";
var cblstTable = document.getElementById(sender.id);
var checkBoxPrefix = sender.id + "_";
var noOfOptions = cblstTable.rows.length;
var selectedText = "";
var countAll = 0;
for (i = 0; i < noOfOptions; ++i) {
    if (document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).checked) {
        countAll += 1;
        if (selectedText == "") {
            if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
                selectedText = document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.textContent;
                valuetodisplay = document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.textContent;
            }
            else {
                selectedText = document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.innerText;
                valuetodisplay = document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.innerText;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
                selectedText = selectedText + "," + document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.textContent;
                valuetodisplay = valuetodisplay + ", " + document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.textContent;
            }
            else {
                selectedText = selectedText + "," + document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.innerText;
                valuetodisplay = valuetodisplay + ", " + document.getElementById(checkBoxPrefix + i).parentNode.innerText;
            }
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('hdnSelectedValues').value = selectedText;
document.getElementById('ctl00_hdnSelectedValuesForDisplay').value = valuetodisplay;
if (noOfOptions == countAll) {
    ChkAll.checked = true;
    document.getElementById('ctl00_hdnSelectedValuesForDisplay').value = "ALL";
}
else {
    if (selectedText == "") {
        ChkAll.checked = false;
        document.getElementById('ctl00_hdnSelectedValuesForDisplay').value = "ALL";
    }
    else {
        ChkAll.checked = false;            
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does it throw any error on browser's console?

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos no it doesn't

Comment: i'm just guessing but one console.log('i am in else') check or replace innerText with textContent might work or put the html and js in sandbox see if works and look at the spx

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos just realised that in chrome, when i select a CheckBox in the ComboBox, the following error is thrown "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and the error line is blank line at the the very, very top of the .aspx file that hosts the control.

Comment: @StackTrace Hmmm.. I advice you to check the syntax of all your JS code that is used in this page with the following tool: http://jshint.com and check if there's any errors.